# Get helm rollback image version

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I'm using a C# code to run the command `helm rollback <ImageName>` to rollback to the previous version (by creating `new Proccess()` with helm).

Is there a way to know the tag of the image the command rolled back to?

Comment: `helm rollback` applied with revision # of a released. Are you saying how to get image tag of the released?

Comment: @gohm'c you don't have to supply the version and then it rollbacks to the previous version, so I want to know how to find out the version it rolled back to if I didn't supply a specific version. What you said can also work if I can just get somehow the tag of a release in general but I don't know how to do that as well

Comment: Yes, but you wrote there helm rollback `<ImageName>` ... so you actually meant the revision #, implicit or explicitly. Also, `Is there a way to know the tag of the image the command rolled back to?` really means is again the release revision #, NOT the image:tag in the released chart itself.

Comment: Is this understanding of your question correct?

Comment: @gohm'c <ImageName> is the release name. You need to tell rollback what release to actually rollback.. if you don't supply the revision number like in my case, it will automatically rollback to the previous release. And the tag is kinda the version since that's how images are stored in the repo with their tag as their version

Comment: Nothing in the visible `helm history` or similar metadata records what tag(s) specific Deployment(s) may have used.  Potentially [`helm get values --revision ??`](https://docs.helm.sh/docs/helm/helm_get_values/) has the information you need, but it will be chart-specific (if the tag is fixed in the YAML files it won't be visible there either).

Answer (score 0):

### Environment

Small cluster with 2 helm charts deployed:

- [ingress-nginx](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/deploy/#using-helm)
- [traefik](https://doc.traefik.io/traefik/getting-started/install-traefik/#use-the-helm-chart)

`helm` v3.7.0 is used.

Also [yq](https://snapcraft.io/install/yq/ubuntu) was installed to work with output in yaml in the similar way `jq` works with json.

### Rollback logic

If no `revision` is set, rollback will be performed on previous `revision`. If `rollback` is run again without `revision`, previous one again will be used.

```
$ helm history traefik
REVISION        UPDATED                         STATUS          CHART           APP VERSION     DESCRIPTION     
1               Tue Oct 12 11:28:22 2021        superseded      traefik-10.3.5  2.5.3           Install complete
2               Tue Oct 12 11:42:47 2021        superseded      traefik-10.3.6  2.5.3           Upgrade complete
3               Tue Oct 12 11:44:32 2021        superseded      traefik-10.3.2  2.5.1           Upgrade complete
4               Tue Oct 12 12:03:26 2021        superseded      traefik-10.3.6  2.5.3           Rollback to 2   
5               Tue Oct 12 13:26:02 2021        deployed        traefik-10.3.2  2.5.1           Rollback to 3
6               Tue Oct 12 13:26:53 2021        deployed        traefik-10.3.6  2.5.3           Rollback to 4
```

So to figure out details of the rolled back revision, we can use current revision.

The same way it can be used to find details from other `revisions`, flag `--revision XX` will be used, for example

```
$ helm get manifest traefik --revision 3
```

### Answer

After some research I found at least 3 options where this information can be retrieved:

1. From [manifest](https://helm.sh/docs/helm/helm_get_manifest/) which was applied (most precise approach):

   ```
   $ helm get manifest ingress-nginx -n ingress-nginx | yq eval '.spec.template.spec.containers[].image' - | grep -oE '[v]?[0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9]'
   v1.0.0

   $ helm get manifest traefik | yq eval '.spec.template.spec.containers[].image' - | grep -oE '[v]?[0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9]'
   2.5.3
   ```

   Using `yq` in this example, because `helm manifest` provides output only in `yaml`:

   > $ helm get manifest --help
   >
   > This command fetches the generated manifest for a given release.
   >
   > A manifest is a YAML-encoded representation of the Kubernetes
   > resources that were generated from this release's chart(s). If a chart
   > is dependent on other charts, those resources will also be included in
   > the manifest.
2. From [values](https://docs.helm.sh/docs/helm/helm_get_values/) (not always works, depends on a chart and/or if image details are located in `values.yaml` or were set using `--set` flag):

   ```
   $ helm get values ingress-nginx --all -n ingress-nginx -o json | jq '.controller.image.tag' 
   "v1.0.0"

   $ helm get values traefik --all -o json | jq '.controller.image.tag'
   null
   ```
3. From kubernetes secrets (most difficult):

   All `revisions` are stored as `secrets` in the same namespace where `chart` is deployed, for instance:

   ```
   $ kubectl get secrets
   NAME                            TYPE                                  DATA   AGE
   sh.helm.release.v1.traefik.v1   helm.sh/release.v1                    1      134m
   sh.helm.release.v1.traefik.v2   helm.sh/release.v1                    1      119m
   sh.helm.release.v1.traefik.v3   helm.sh/release.v1                    1      118m
   sh.helm.release.v1.traefik.v4   helm.sh/release.v1                    1      99m
   sh.helm.release.v1.traefik.v5   helm.sh/release.v1                    1      16m
   sh.helm.release.v1.traefik.v6   helm.sh/release.v1                    1      15m
   ```

   The way the data is stored in these `secrets` is [even more complicated](https://gist.github.com/DzeryCZ/c4adf39d4a1a99ae6e594a183628eaee), however `image tag` can be retrieved from it as well. Provided link contains details on how to extract data from these `secrets`.

   Here's a quote of command to decode one of the secrets:

   ```
   kubectl get secrets sh.helm.release.v1.wordpress.v1 -o json | jq .data.release | tr -d '"' | base64 -d | base64 -d | gzip -d
   ```

### Useful links:

- [helm get manifest](https://helm.sh/docs/helm/helm_get_manifest/)
- [helm get values](https://docs.helm.sh/docs/helm/helm_get_values/)

Comment: @WytrzymałyWiktor I eventually ended up using a DB we already had which saves the versions instead of getting it from the helm command.. I don't know if this solution works and will accept it if there are other comments saying it worked